# Top 2 boxES and bottom 2 boxes netting in R using expss package

Tags: r, expss

How to provide top 2 boxes and bottom 2 box netting in R using `Expss` package?

How to create data tables with Question Text, netting, Mean, Median with stubs?

Please find the example tables from this link.
[Here is the sample tables which i wanted to create using R function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyTaw.png)

Comment: You will get more useful answers if you make it easier for people to help you.  Post your data using the `dput` command, and show what you expect in text, not a picture.

Comment: What does it mean 'sigma' on your example>

Comment: @GregoryDemin 'sigma' means total number of respondents except Top 2 Box (Net) and Bottom 2 Box (Net) count. if you add up all stubs counts, then sigma should be equal to Total base for single select question and in multi select case sigma should be either equal to base of more than total base. please let me know if it is clear.